# How to navigate between screens on the Mac

Tags: macos, keyboard, window-manager, switching

Cmd+tab is like the task switcher in Windows, except it only pulls the menu bar up for the application, and not the application itself.

Q: How do I switch between applications such that the application is visible?

Comment: Unlike Windows, OSX doesn't require windows to be open for an application to continue running.  So when you hit 'x' on (most) applications it will leave just a menu bar with zero open windows.

Comment: I pressed the minimize button, not the 'x'.

Comment: cmd - tab doesn't show minimized windows

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking what I think you're asking, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> will usually cycle between application windows within a single application.

It's also possible you have no application windows open, and you're just getting a menu bar.

Also, this should probably be in the superuser stackexchange.

Comment: I've got Finder and Xcode open, and I can't navigate to either of them using the keyboard.

Comment: Do have any windows open in either of them?

Comment: Yes, I have windows open in Xcode, but not Finder.

Comment: Ah, I see from your above comment that you've minimized a window. I can't test this now, but it seems that pressing `cmd`+`tab` until you've selected the application and then pressing `option` while releasing will restore the last minimized window. Other than that, I don't know of any way to restore minimized windows. I honestly don't minimize things on OS X very often for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 3):

The application switching process is nearly the same as on Windows (& step 5 is optional :-):

1. <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to your application.
2. Release <kbd>Tab</kbd>, but keep holding <kbd>Command</kbd>.
3. Press <kbd>Option</kbd> (which in Mac-Speak is the same as <kbd>Alt</kbd>).
4. Release <kbd>Command</kbd>.
5. Make smarmy comment about how things are simpler on a Mac.

Comment: I've used MacOS X since the beginning, and even I didn't know this trick to show hidden windows. Simpler? Maybe. Intuitive? Not in this case. :)

Comment: That's bizarre. Why go through all that when you can just command-H to hide an app and then have it appear automatically when you command-tab to it?